# ESP32 MOSFET Control with a Twist

Tags: arduino, mosfet, lipo, esp32, bms

Looking for some help with using an ESP32 (running Arduino IDE) to control a MOSFET. Currently, I have used the combo to control many things successfully by electronically "pressing buttons" by shorting the button contacts. I'm having trouble shorting two pins of a BMS (Battery Management System) for a LiPo battery that when shorted by a switch, enable the main battery output.

The BMS has 12v on one of the pins, and Ground on the other, and shorting them draws 0.04mA between them.

Problem is, when I enable the MOSFET with the ESP32, the BMS doesn't detect a short but does when physically shorted.

3.3V is present, and the MOSFET turns on after a few seconds of code, confirmed by continuity on a multimeter that collector/emitter are now connected.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

How does the BMS know that the short is done with a MOSFET rather than a switch?

MOSFET is FQP30N06L 
[(Datasheet)](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP30N06L.pdf)

Also, is the GND on the emitter required seeing as there is a common ground between everything anyway?

Comment: There is no telling what this system would do, no information on the BMS is given. What is the mosfet? Is it pmos or nmos? It would be rather unusually to see a BMS with only a connection on ground as there is no way for the BMS to monitor the voltage on the positive terminal of the battery.

Comment: The comparison between Active and Mechanical switch is always done by Voltage drop @ some current. Perhaps your Gate drive is not 2.5 to 3x Vgs(on)=1~2.5V for said FET to match the switch resistance or BMS threshold

Comment: @Voltage Spike The BMS is an Evolve Electric Skateboard BMS which is impossible to find the datasheet on sadly, but the positive comes directly out from the battery, with the ground and balance leads off to the BMS. It's a N channel, would that make a difference in this case?

Comment: @Tony That's a great idea! I will compare the resistance of the usual switch to the FET and see if I can match them. Thanks!

Comment: That means Vgs>=10V to get Ron=35 mOhm